# assigning values in a new column -- efficiency, please

Tags: r, dataframe, assign

I'm looking for a more efficient way of doing a very basic task: adding a new column with values specified for existing rows.  The sample dataframe (called ess) has country and (survey) round.  I want to add a column "dem", with values from an external source.  Here's a snippet:

```
id cntry essround dem
1 AL       1
2 AT       1
3 BE       1
4 BG       1
5 HR       1
6 AL       2
7 AT       2
8 BE       2
9 BG       2
10 HR      2
```

The "long" way of doing this is as follows:

```
ess$dem <- NA
ess$dem[ess$cntry=="AL" & ess$essround==1] <- 3.5
ess$dem[ess$cntry=="AT" & ess$essround==1] <- 1
ess$dem[ess$cntry=="BE" & ess$essround==1] <- 1.5
ess$dem[ess$cntry=="BG" & ess$essround==1] <- 2
ess$dem[ess$cntry=="HR" & ess$essround==1] <- 2
ess$dem[ess$cntry=="AL" & ess$essround==2] <- 3
ess$dem[ess$cntry=="AT" & ess$essround==2] <- 1
ess$dem[ess$cntry=="BE" & ess$essround==2] <- 1
ess$dem[ess$cntry=="BG" & ess$essround==2] <- 1.5
ess$dem[ess$cntry=="HR" & ess$essround==2] <- 2
```

The problem is, this way of doing it gets *very* long, when I have 36 countries and 6 rounds -- I end up with 216 lines of code that way.  (It gets worse when I want to create multiple new columns in the same mode...)

Is there no way of condensing an operation like this??  Can it be done on a single line where the code relies on "position" in corresponding lists of values?

Comment: Are you looking for `ess$dem <- c(3.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1.5, 2)`?

Comment: well, can you give us some sample df to work with? how does the df contining `dem` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tidyverse` first you need to create a data.frame that'll contain the values: ie `ess$dem[ess$cntry=="AL" & ess$essround==1] <- 3.5` should become a row in `conds` data.frame:

```r
## expand grid to create all possible combinations of cntry and essround
conds <- expand.grid(cntry=c("AL","AT","BE","BG","HR"), essround=1:2) %>% mutate(dem = c(3.5,1,1.5,2,2,3,1,1,1.5,2))
## first row will be "AL" 1 3.5 which is the first condition
conds
   cntry essround dem
1     AL        1 3.5
2     AT        1 1.0
3     BE        1 1.5
4     BG        1 2.0
5     HR        1 2.0
6     AL        2 3.0
7     AT        2 1.0
8     BE        2 1.0
9     BG        2 1.5
10    HR        2 2.0
ess %>% left_join(conds)
Joining, by = c("cntry", "essround")
   cntry essround dem
1     AT        1 1.0
2     AT        2 1.0
3     HR        2 2.0
4     BG        2 1.5
5     HR        2 2.0
6     HR        1 2.0
7     BG        2 1.5
8     BG        1 2.0
9     HR        2 2.0
10    BG        1 2.0
11    AT        1 1.0
12    BG        2 1.5
13    AL        1 3.5
14    HR        1 2.0
15    BE        2 1.0
16    AL        2 3.0
17    AL        1 3.5
18    AL        1 3.5
19    AT        1 1.0
20    AT        1 1.0
```

Comment: Thanks -- that works.  Left_join -- now I get it.  I set up the second dataframe (containing the "conditions") in Excel -- that's easy enough, and better than having hundreds of lines of code...

Comment: @dbartram also by default rows that have no matching condition will be assigned `NA`

Answer (score 1):

Creating dummy data:

```
ess = data.frame(
contry = sample(c("AL","AT","BE","BG","HR","AL","AT","BE","BG","HR"), 20, TRUE),
essround = sample(1:2, 20, TRUE))
```

Now the code:

```
ess$dem <- NA

values = c(3.5,1,1.5,2,2,3,1,1,1.5,2)
groups = unique(ess$contry)

for(i in 1:length(groups)){
  ess[ess$contry==groups[i],"dem"] <- values[i]
}
```

Output:

```
   contry essround dem
1      BE        1 3.5
2      HR        2 1.0
3      AT        2 1.5
4      BG        1 2.0
5      AT        1 1.5
6      AT        2 1.5
7      AT        2 1.5
8      AT        2 1.5
9      BG        2 2.0
10     BE        2 3.5
11     AT        1 1.5
12     AT        2 1.5
13     BE        1 3.5
14     AT        2 1.5
15     HR        1 1.0
16     BG        1 2.0
17     BE        1 3.5
18     BG        1 2.0
19     AT        2 1.5
20     AT        2 1.5
```